# How can postgresql have a "lost update" in Read Committed isolation level?

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, lost-update

On page 52 of *PostgreSQL 14 Internals*, Egor Rogov indicates that "lost updates" can occur with the "Read Committed" isolation level. There is also a sentence that reads:

> But in *some cases*, there is a risk of losing
> changes at the `Read Committed` level.

I would like to understand what one of the (special?) cases is. Under what circumstance does this anomaly happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is *there's no such case*.

The *special case* the author has in mind isn't one where Postgres can lose an update, it's where the larger system Postgres is a part of, appears to lose an update. The case in question requires users in concurrent transactions to re-use values read previously, disregarding the fact that between the initial read and its re-use, someone's commit might have rendered the value outdated.

Thing is, if you want to do things that way, you're supposed to use [`repeatable read` mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) and/or [`select for update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) (or another [explicit lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html)), locking the rows you plan to update.

In the [PDF version](https://edu.postgrespro.com/postgresql_internals-14_part1_en.pdf) the quote you refer to is on page 44. Page 52 describes said case of lost update:

> The application reads and registers
> (outside of the database) the current balance of Alice’s account:
>
> ```sql
>  => BEGIN;
>  => SELECT amount FROM accounts WHERE id = 1;
>  amount
>  −−−−−−−−
>  800.00
>  (1 row)
> ```
>
> Meanwhile, the other transaction does the same:
>
> ```sql
>  => BEGIN;
>  => SELECT amount FROM accounts WHERE id = 1;
>  amount
>  −−−−−−−−
>  800.00
>  (1 row)
> ```
>
> The first transaction increases the previously registered value by $800 and commits
> this change:
>
> ```sql
> => UPDATE accounts SET amount = 800.00 + 100 WHERE id = 1
> RETURNING amount;
> amount
> −−−−−−−−
> 900.00
> (1 row)
> UPDATE 1
> => COMMIT;
> ```
>
> The second transaction does the same:
>
> ```sql
> => UPDATE accounts SET amount = 800.00 + 100 WHERE id = 1
> RETURNING amount;
> amount
> −−−−−−−−
> 900.00
> (1 row)
> UPDATE 1
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, Alice has lost $100. The database system does not know that the registered value of $800 is somehow related to accounts.amount, so it cannot prevent the lost update anomaly. At the Read Committed isolation level, this code is incorrect.